# How can view but not print a text from an OpenOffice pdf exported file

Tags: pdf, openoffice

I have this pdf file completely generated from

```
Mac 10.9.3 + OpenOffice 4.0.1
OpenOffice Draw -> File -> Export as PDF... -> File1.pdf
```

The original `File1.odg` file was created with FormFields and
they are working as expected in the `File1.pdf`.

How can I

- let my users see the `File1.pdf` as is,
- let users use it to enter data in the FormFields,

But send to the **printer** (when they print) 
**only populated information in the FormFields**, 
to work like a stencil ?

Comment: Programming will be involve, eventually, but I am trying to acheive it with available menus for now, so Ok, how can I transfer my question ?

Comment: It's been flagged so a moderator should be moving it soon